# Send back response string to use in jQuery's ajax function

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a function for making a post request.

```
$('#save').click( function() {
  ...
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'logic/save.php',
    data: { 'json': JSON.stringify( post ) },
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: function( data ) {
      console.log('success!')
    }
  });
}
```

The request handler is written in php, as you can see, and performs operations with mysql. Because of my poor knowledge of php and requests, I do not see any **success!** output in the console. Php code runs fine, and the mysql queries runs with no errors.

What I want is to be able to write something in php code at the end so that my code in js could receive it as a positive response (like 200, OK) and the **success!** line in the console will then (I believe) appears.

What code should I add to the php file?

**UPDATE:** since many of people requested the php code, here's the [link](http://pastebin.com/9AtUyjZM) to it. Thank you for fast replies, guys.

Comment: where is the php code?

Comment: Are you sure the `data: { 'json': JSON.stringify( post ) },` line is right? Shouldn't it just be `data: post,`?

Comment: You shouldn't be using jsonp either (unless you have made the appropriate server side changes which I assume you have not), which is likely your _actual_ problem preventing the success block from executing. Change your `dataType` to json.

Comment: @Matt I think it's OK. OP is sending an object with a key named `json` and the string value of `JSON.stringify(post)`.

Comment: Please show your PHP code. Are you trying to use jsonp on purpose, or is json OK? Or is a plain text response (as per "response string" in your question title) OK?

Comment: Try to add `error` handler.

Comment: @SnowBlind While it's possible, it's pretty illogical to make PHP decode JSON as a string instead of just accepting post parameters...unless there's a valid reason for doing so.

Comment: **Matt** yes, 100% sure, using the firefox's firebug and can see that mysql query runs ok with passed data. **ColinMorelli** I have tried to change jsonp to json, and the results are the same, unfortunately. **jbabey** I doubt there's need in my existing php code since there's only one sql query which execures with no errors.

Comment: @Astro There is absolutely a need in your PHP code. Examples: is your PHP responding with 200 OK? Are you sending back valid JSON? Are you sending any other output back to the client besides the JSON? If using JSONP, are you using the callback parameter? Etc.

Comment: @ColinMorelli I totally agree, I'm just saying that syntax is correct.

Comment: @SnowBlind Fair point, though those kinds of things are usually some of the first I point out when people have problems because it's hard to believe that someone would do them intentionally :).

Comment: Check out **update** section, guys, I have linked the php code for you.

Comment: @Astro Good thing you posted your code - because it _is_ the problem :). You're not returning JSON back from the endpoint. Your jQuery is expecting it (because you have set `dataType` to json/jsonp). You need to `json_encode` an array, for example, and send that back to the client. Or use a `dataType` other than JSON. I'll answer for you shortly.

Comment: Just in case, try add `, error: function (msg) { alert("Error: " + msg); }` to ensure.

Comment: @PiLHA I have added this code and yes, I get an error with message **Error: [object Object]**

Comment: @Astro Then your ajax call is broken. Try update `data: { 'json': JSON.stringify( post ) },` to `data: "{ json: ' + JSON.stringify(post) + "'}"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, you should switch from jsonp to json, as you have no need for jsonp in this case. The following instructions assume you have made that change.

The bug is in your PHP code when you respond back to the client. You do so with this line:

```
print_r( "New item inserted.\n" );
```

However, jQuery is expecting you to be returning JSON back from your endpoint (and, truthfully, it should, because sending back plaintext to an ajax client is almost never the right way). We can make this work with jQuery by changing the line above to something like this:

```
print json_encode( array('success' => true, 'message' => "New item inserted." ) );
```

You should find yourself in the success callback in your client. This code would work for your success handler:

```
{ // ...,
    success: function(response) {
        if (response.success) {
            alert(response.message);
        }
    }
}
```

You'll probably want to use something other than an alert, though. But that's up to you.

Comment: _"jQuery is expecting you to be returning JSON back from your endpoint"_ - The OP's code is expecting jsonp, not json. (I know you go on to talk about changing the `dataType`, but initially you're talking about what the current code is expecting.) In any case, +1.

Comment: @nnnnnn Valid point, updated the answer and now it's the first sentence

Comment: Here's what I did. I have changed jsonp to json, removed any echo and print_r inside the php code, and added there array with success line. Unfortunately, I got the alert pop up window. Then I noticed that @colin-morelli edited the post, I used the edited version and **success!**. Thank you guys!

Comment: @Astro Yeah, my pre-edited code didn't actually `json_encode` the response lol - in other words, I was doing exactly what I was trying to tell you not to be doing. But I'm glad it's working now.